# how to fix the error: Error in importIntoEnv(pkgenv, exports, nsenv, exports),cannot add bindings to a locked environment devtools-roxygen2?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

After updating Rstudio and macOS, my package is no more loadable with devtools:

```
devtools::load_all(".")
```

> Loading mgwrsar
>
> Error in importIntoEnv(pkgenv, exports, nsenv, exports) : 
>             cannot add bindings to a locked environment

I update the following packages: [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools), [roxygen2](/questions/tagged/roxygen2) and `rstudioapi`, but it doesn't resolve this issue

I try to switch to hadley devtools version : `install_github("hadley/devtools")`

same issue.

My session info :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    yaml_2.1.19
```

Comment: Do you assign anything to the global environment in your package? On a related note, is your package code available publicly, for example in a GitHub repo?

Comment: You're probably right, but I didn't find how and where some object can be assign to the global environment. The 0.1 version of my package is on gitHub https://github.com/cran/mgwrsar, but I face this issue with the develop version which is not on gitHub. I will test if a Rstudio project based on this 0.1 version also provides the same error.

Comment: I go back to the 0.1 version of my package, save it as a new Rstudio .proj: it doesn't suffer this problem. So I make my changes again. The R scripts are the same at the end but now it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get this error from calling library(package) from within the package itself.

Comment: Thanks @barnhillec that was what resolved it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Duckmayr's response helped me solve my issue for this same problem:

Do you assign anything to the global environment in your package?

I had saved a new R script in my package project as mypackage/R/myscript.R instead of mypackage/separate_testing_folder/myscript.R. Of course, nothing but actual code pertaining to definition of functions etc should be saved in any scripts within the R/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was accidentally referencing the name of my package INSIDE of my DESCRIPTION. Woops, something like this - I fixed it like so.

```
Package: utilities
Depends:
    dplyr,    # and comma here
    utilities # remove this
```